# How can I execute node file from nw application

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

I have created a nw.js desktop application. My requirement is to read data from HID devices. So am using node-hid module. I have written code specific to read and parsing data in usbreader.js file.

In my main.html file am trying to execute node command like below:

```
exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('node usbreader.js', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error !== null) {
    console.log(stderr);
  }
  else{
    console.log(stdout);
  }
});
```

But am getting error saying:

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Please help me how can I execute this node js file from nw application

Comment: Your solution would require node to be installed on the system where you are running your app. Although your app runs on node it's not available in command line like this. Can't you simply require the file in your script?

Comment: Where is your node executable located? You can do 'which node' on Linux or similar in your os.

Comment: @Molda require didn't work for me. I don't think node-hid is fully compatible with nwjs. So i found this way.

Comment: @SrikanthKshatriy if node-hid didn't compile and you are using NW v0.12.3 then it's known issue and you can try NW v0.8.6

Answer (score 0):

If your `usbreader` is compatible with your nwjs node version, then you can use it in next way:

```
usbreader = require('usbreader');
```

If you want to run it in separate process in node, then you need to install node for your OS. And code is next;

```
exec = require('child_process').exec;
var usbreaderProc = exec('node usbreader.js', { cwd: '/path/to/usbreader/dir' } function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error !== null) {
    console.log(stderr);
  }
  else{
    console.log(stdout);
  }
});
```